# React Native execute a function after fetch has ended

Tags: javascript, function, reactjs, native, fetch

The problem I have is that when I change the page, the fetch hasn't still ended the fetching so some variables are empty. I need that until the fetch function is completely done he doesn't call the next function. Here are the 2 functions conflicting:

```js
  componentDidMount() { 
 this.fetchData();  

 setTimeout(() => {
  InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {   
    this.setState({renderPlaceholderOnly: true});   
  });    
    }, 300);
  }
  
  fetchData() {   
  return fetch(REQUEST_URL+this.props.boat.id)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
   this.setState({
    boat2: responseData,
    loaded: true,
    name:responseData.name,
    maker:responseData.maker,
    model:responseData.model,
    buildYear:responseData.buildYear,
    refitYear:responseData.refitYear,
    boatType:responseData.boatType,
    withSkipper:responseData.withSkipper,
    licenseNeeded:responseData.licenseNeeded, 
    places:responseData.places,
    berths:responseData.berths,
    cabins:responseData.cabins,
    toilets:responseData.toilets,
    length:responseData.length,
    beam:responseData.beam,
    draft:responseData.draft,
    motorType:responseData.motorType,
    power:responseData.power,
    maxSpeed:responseData.maxSpeed,
    cruiseSpeed:responseData.cruiseSpeed,
    consumption:responseData.consumption,
    water:responseData.water,
    tank:responseData.tank,
    IMGS : [
      'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1441742917377-57f78ee0e582?h=1024',
      'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1441716844725-09cedc13a4e7?h=1024',
      'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1441448770220-76743f9e6af6?h=1024'
    ],   
   });
   
    })
    .catch((error) => alert(error) )
    .done();     
  }
```

In the `componentDidMount` the fetch is executed but he executes the `interactionManager` before the fetch has ended, that's why I used `setTimeout` as a temporal solution.

Comment: Why don't you use `...` spread operator or even `Object.assign` method?

Comment: @user2849167 could you give feedback?

Comment: Im  new in react native how can i do that in my code? thanks